# git push upstream cannot set permission

Tags: git

I have 2 local git branches.

```
devel
master
```

When i want to update my master branch, i would have to run `git checkout master` and `git merge devel`.

However, i would like to be on my devel branch and run `git push master`.

It throws up an error asking me to run `git push --set-upstream master devel`. However, when i run this command it says i have no permission when i am using the admin account.

Comment: Have you ran `git fetch` or `git pull`?

Comment: looks your local branch has not updated as mangoHero1 saiid always pull remote branch first and then push (I think your devel branch is not updated)

Comment: @mangoHero1 i tried going to master branch and run git fetch or git pull. But it seems it says its not a valid repo.

Comment: Are you working with a remote branch? If you're on `devel` branch, run `git status` and push the commits with `git push -u devel`

Comment: Nope both are local repos @mangoHero1